# silverlight print to pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, silverlight

refrence link is

```
WebResponse resp = hwr.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
```

i am getting error
i inserted

```
<system.web>

  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
```

in my webconfig

but problem is not solve and getting error inner exception is:

> {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error:
>   NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an
>   error: NotFound. at
>   System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__4(Object
>   sendState) at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__1(Object
>   sendState)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback
>   beginMethod, Object state) at
>   System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at PrintToPDF.MainPage.PrintGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asynchronousResult)}

if you want to see my code than download link is
http://180.211.127.222:164/source/

Answer (score 0):

i done this problem using PdfSharp
code is:

```
  using PdfSharp.Pdf;
  using PdfSharp.Drawing;
  using ImageTools.IO.Jpeg;


   private void btnCBEPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SaveFileDialog d = new SaveFileDialog();
            d.Filter = "PDF file format|*.pdf";

            // Save the document...
            if (d.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
                PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
                XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
                ExtendedImage myImage = LayoutRoot.ToImage();
                page.Width = ((ImageTools.ImageBase)(myImage)).Bounds.Width - 300;
                page.Height = ((ImageTools.ImageBase)(myImage)).Bounds.Height;

                MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream();
                JpegEncoder encoder = new JpegEncoder();
                encoder.Quality = 90;
                encoder.Encode(myImage, mstream);
                mstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                XImage pdfImg = XImage.FromStream(mstream);
                gfx.DrawImage(pdfImg, 0, 0);

                //btnSave.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btnCBEPrint.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                document.Save(d.OpenFile());

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```